# why do you keep erasing my comments?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, comments

I added added some comments to [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/60552/11306).

The author did improve the answer, but then commented that the original wording was supported by other sources.

I replied by saying that listing those sources would be informative.

The author listed the sources in the comments.

I replied by saying that the sources should be in the answer rather than comments.  I admit that this was not so cut in dry in the language used.  But I was a bit thrown off by how somewhat hyperbolic formulation in the original answer.

What I don't understand is why are my comments are being removed.  And I mean the latest comments.  The ones which suggest that the links to the sources (listed in the comments) should be incorporated into the answer.

This is the preferred behavior and it is common to ask people not to answer in comments, but rather to add the content to the answers themselves.  So what's up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those comments were flagged by the answer's author, which means that the author read the comments and did whatever she thought appropriate.  In general this sort of "no longer needed" deletion is how and why such comments-to-the-author are cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

### Comments are temporary

It says so right in the [Comment Everywhere](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege:

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

They can get deleted because they were flagged or because a passing mod felt that they were no longer adding to the post but were creating “noise”.

If you want a more permanent record, edit the post or post your own answer or a new question.

All is as it should be.

Answer (score -1):

I did provide YOU the links because you asked for why I wrote it. However, the links have no significance for the matter of the suit itself: the defendant got an exact copy of the other lawsuit because his conduct was the same.

Comment: Don't the links support the claim that the defendants claims are spurious? Your answer seems to be about the merits of Dominion's suit.  If these are links which support Dominion's position, an answer which attempts to explain that position may be improved by those links.